# MySQL installation .. "unable to determine the products that correspond with that setup type" how to solve this..?

Tags: mysql

MySQL installation .. "unable to determine the products that correspond with that setup type" how to solve this.. ??
 i tried every option such as custom , server only, client only etc . But same annoying problem

Comment: You have provided slightly less info, than *none*.

Comment: working.. i restarted and tried the new installation thank you very much

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem. Choose 'custom' and pick the options you want. This will work. Good luck.

Comment: When choosing 'custom' it shows the products on the left and obviously wants you to select one or more and click the arrow to move them to the right. However, selecting an item on the left and clicking the arrow does nothing. The selected item never moves to the right.

Comment: This worked for me, I expanded the products lists, chose the product,  the arrow turned green and when clicked the item moved

Comment: this didn't work for me, see the answer below from Tilman Hausherr

Answer (score 12):

I got it to work. I first had installed the (small) "web" file. The "Catalog" method mentioned by mySql support didn't work, probably because I'm behind a corporate proxy. What did work was

- go to control panel (for germans: "Systemsteuerung")
- deinstall "MySQL installer - community"
- download the non-web file, i.e. the one that is almost 300MB large
- run that one and choose the components you need.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Running the 'latest' msi installer from the mysql website downloads the small installer and it will never work. uninstall that installer as outlined above. Go to the 'previous versions' on the mysql website and download that msi installer. It is 200-300 meg instead of 1-2 meg. That installer will now work.

Answer (score 3):

Open "MySQL Installer - Community" from the Start menu (not the .msi file). Then click "Catalog", get the required update, and then the installation should work.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,624707,624888#msg-624888

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I used Web community edition.
So,

- I installed full edition.
- Picked Custom option
- Picked WorkBench(which is what I needed). Transfer arrow was still grayed out
- Drilled down all the way to the last under workbench. Transfer arrow lighted up. I was able to select and install. Similarly I installed other required as well.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I think it's related to UAC (User Account Control) when installing the small community edition.

Go to Start-MySQL-My SQL Installer
then right click the shortcut and "Run As Administrator".

This allows the updater to update itself and continue.  No more error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and went the custom route. The issue I then had was that the MS Visual C++ 2013 runtime edition was not installed on my machine. Once I downloaded and installed that from Microsoft, all was well.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, it's the solution to the problem for me.